# How to “filter” out one specific user in a view?

Tags: views

I’ve a question regarding some of my blocks which I’ve made in views (using Drupal 6 and Views 2). One of the users on the site is the sites “manager” and so this user of cause writes a lot of posts, comment on a lot of posts and “likes” a lot of posts.

In some of my blocks I display the most contributing users and this “manager” is almost always on top of the list and I would like to display the most contributing users, but “ignore” this user.

My views are very simple and basic created. For example in one I list the most commenting users right now (that be, the last 24 hours) and I sort according to the comment count.
In this example, how do I “filter” out the one user?

Thanks

Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your view filter out the user:

1. **Add relationships:** Node revision: User
   **Label:** user
   **Require this relationship:** (checked)
2. **Add filters:** User: Name
   **Relationship:** user
   **Is not one of:** manager

Comment: Thank you so very much Jan, it works perfectly.
This is a nice snippet to save and you saved me a bunch of work trying to figure out a solution.